# How do I add 'list' attribute to an input field using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, django, ajax, django-templates, html-lists

I'm struggling to figure out the following;

I have a django form field hidden in `{{ field.field }}`. It renders out as

```
<input type="text" name="field-id" value="100" id="id_set-0-product" class="vForeignKeyRawIdAdminField">
```

I can tagret it using jQuery by its id but I need to add a `list = "choicelist"` which corresponds with

```
<datalist id="choicelist" style="text-align: center">
                            </datalist>
```

which I populate using ajax requests. How do I add the `list = "choicelist"` to it? I am basically looking for something like .addClass() but for a list.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: you want to add **list** in input field like this - <input type="text" name="field-id" value="100" list="choicelist" id="id_set-0-product" class="vForeignKeyRawIdAdminField"> ?

Comment: This is exactly it

Comment: added answer please check it. for both using id and class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the [attr()](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) method for this:

```
 $('#id_set-0-product').attr('list', 'choicelist')
```

Comment: thank you, only the # in ('#id_set-0-product') was missing but it solved the problem, thank you.

Comment: oh yea sorry about that, i approved your edit! youre welcome!

Answer (score 1):

You have two options

Using ID (it will add list attribute for particular field)

```
  $('#id_set-0-product').attr('list', 'choicelist')
```

Using Class (it will add list attribute for all available field with the same class)

```
$('.vForeignKeyRawIdAdminField').attr('list', 'choicelist')
```

Comment: You actually solved the problem that came right after that haha, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Using Django, [add the attribute to the widget](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.Widget.attrs):

> attrs
>
> A dictionary containing HTML attributes to be set on the rendered widget.

```py
    >>> from django import forms
    >>> name = forms.TextInput(attrs={'size': 10, 'title': 'Your name'})
    >>> name.render('name', 'A name')
    '<input title="Your name" type="text" name="name" value="A name" size="10">'
```